# Modify routes and url when using Varnish

Tags: php, twig, slim, slim-4

I have a project where Varnish is used in front of a Slim 4 project. Due to some project specialities, the original url should be hidden and the incoming request is rewritten to some other headers.

**Example**

- Original call to demo.xyz is coming to Varnish
- Varnish is transforming the request to `http://slimapp.dev/url/demo.xyz`
- The original host is saved in the header with `X-Orig-Host: demo.xyz`

The Slim App needs to detect if it is a Varnish request (I already got that) and needs to transform the routes.

**Routes**

Without Varnish:

```php
$app->group('/url/{url}', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
    $group->get('[/city/{city}]', IndexAction::class)->setName('home');
    $group->get('/search[/{query}]', SearchQueryAction::class)->setName('search-query');
});
```

With Varnish:

```php
$app->get('[/city/{city}]', IndexAction::class)->setName('home');
$app->get('/search[/{query}]', SearchQueryAction::class)->setName('search-query');
```

So when creating a route with `url_for` ([Twig-View package](https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View)) the urls should be generated like that:

- Route w/o Varnish: `http://slimapp.dev/url/demo.xyz/article/123`
- Route w/ Varnish: `http://demo.xyz/article/123`

**Ideas:**

1. Modify the original UriInterface object but I have no idea how.
2. Write a TwigExtension for Twig-View to modify the methods for `url_for` and so on.

The first ideas feels kind of more reliable and the right place to do. The other one would mean I would need to overwrite the helper methods to build the url based on the `X-Orig-Host`.

Any idea how I can modify the Uri / probably overwriting the `create` method?

Thanks in advance!

P. S.: The same questions I placed in [Slim Discourse](https://discourse.slimframework.com/t/varnish-proxy-modify-routes-and-urls-of-slim-4-application/3744/2).

**UPDATE 1**

**routes.php**

```php
return function (App $app) {

    $app->get('/', function () {
        die('No URL defined.');
    })->setName('root');

    $app->group('/url/{url}', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
        $group->get('[/city/{city}]', IndexAction::class)->setName('home');

        # Internal page search
        $group->get('/search[/{query}]', SearchQueryAction::class)->setName('search-query');
    });

};
```

**middleware.php**

```php
return function(App $app) {
    $c = $app->getContainer();

    $app->addBodyParsingMiddleware();
    $app->add(TwigMiddleware::class);
    $app->addRoutingMiddleware();
    $app->add(VarnishBasePathMiddleware::class);

    $displayErrorDetails = $c->get(Configuration::class)->getBool('displayErrorDetails');
    $errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware($displayErrorDetails, false, false);
    $errorHandler = $errorMiddleware->getDefaultErrorHandler();
    $errorHandler->registerErrorRenderer('text/html', HtmlErrorRenderer::class);
    $errorHandler->registerErrorRenderer('application/json', JsonErrorRenderer::class);
};
```

**Error message**

```
[404] Not found. in /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php on line 91.

Backtrace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/RoutingMiddleware.php(57): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #1 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous)) #2 /usr/share/nginx/html/src/Middleware/VarnishBasePathMiddleware.php(28): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(180): App\Middleware\VarnishBasePathMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous)) #4 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/twig-view/src/TwigMiddleware.php(125): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #5 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(180): Slim\Views\TwigMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous)) #6 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/ErrorMiddleware.php(89): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #7 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(132): Slim\Middleware\ErrorMiddleware->process(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request), Object(class@anonymous)) #8 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(73): class@anonymous->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #9 /usr/share/nginx/html/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(208): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #10 /usr/share/nginx/html/public/index.php(57): Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #11 {main}
```

Comment: The Twig-View `url_for` function returns just the path and not the full url, . e.g.: `/hello/world`. Why do you need to change the full url then?

Comment: Good point. I need to change the full URL because when using Varnish it should show the URL like the one that was requested and not the one from the Slim app behind. Now when I run the app w/ Varnish I request/open http://demo.xyz but all the links/routes generated are http://slimapp.dev/url/demo.xyz. So everyone sees the real URL from the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement you own `ServerRequestCreatorInterface` class like this:

```php
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Slim\Factory\ServerRequestCreatorFactory;
use Slim\Interfaces\ServerRequestCreatorInterface;
use Slim\Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory;

class VarnishServerRequestCreator implements ServerRequestCreatorInterface
{
    public function createServerRequestFromGlobals(): ServerRequestInterface
    {
        $request = ServerRequestFactory::createFromGlobals();
        $serverParams = $request->getServerParams();

        if (isset($serverParams['X-Orig-Host'])) {
            // Replace the hostname
            $uri = $request->getUri()->withHost($serverParams['X-Orig-Host']);
            $request = $request->withUri($uri);
        }

        return $request;
    }
}

ServerRequestCreatorFactory::setServerRequestCreator(new VarnishServerRequestCreator());
```

To output the full url in your Twig templates use the `full_url_for` function. Example:

```
{{ full_url_for('article') }}
```

Output:

`https://demo.xyz/article`

To change the base path you could add this special middleware:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Slim\App;

final class VarnishBasePathMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var App The slim app
     */
    private $app;

    public function __construct(App $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
    }

    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $serverParams = $request->getServerParams();

        // Detect Varnish
        if (isset($serverParams['X-Orig-Host'])) {
            // Change the base path
            $this->app->setBasePath('/url/demo.xyz');
        }

        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

The `VarnishBasePathMiddleware` must be add after the `RoutingMiddleware`

```php
$app->add(TwigMiddleware::class);

$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

$app->add(\App\Middleware\VarnishBasePathMiddleware::class); // <--- here

$app->addErrorMiddleware(...)
```

Comment: I like the second option, but this would mean also to write my own (or at least inheric from it) Psr7\Factory\ServerRequestFactory and Psr7\Factory\UriFactory in which I then read the proper host not from HTTP_HOST but from X-Orig-Host, am I right?

Comment: You only have to change the host. I just updated the answer to show you the real example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works very well! As the routes needs to work w/ and w/o Varnish I created a second routes files `routes_with_varnish.php` which is included when a Varnish req happens. It just removes the `url/{url}` in front of all routes. Doesn't feel very clean, but I have no other idea  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Any ideas on that?

Comment: I just update the answer. To change the base path add the `VarnishBasePathMiddleware` middleware, change the path according to your needs and remove the redundant routing file.

Comment: I implemented the changes like described, but for the reqs with Varnish I always get `404 Not Found`. The base path is correctly set. I updated my post with details from my `routes.php` and `middleware.php`. Any idea?

Comment: Slim is LIFO. You should also put the TwigMiddleware before the RoutingMiddleware.  $app->addRoutingMiddleware();`

Comment: Still no look. Put it in the right order (all others, routing, varnish, error,... updated the code sample), but still getting the 404. Only the Varnish reqs are affected. The ones without run fine.

Comment: Have you checked to ports and the varnish configuration? Is is http or https? Check the Varnish log file for more details.

Comment: That was it. Misconfiguration of Varnish. Thanks again. Everything works now.

Comment: Sorry, to get back to this topic, but when setting `/url/X-Orig-Host` as base path, it is not recognized anymore as query param, which leads to the problem that the routes are not found and further I cannot use the `url` param in my controllers etc. So what I need is, that it is not visible in URL but still accessible as a query param. Not sure how to tackle this.