# Slim 4 - Base path as query param

Tags: php, slim, slim-4

I have a Slim 4 app running and set some recurring url param as a base path to not show this in url generation.

**Request flows:**

1. Call to `http:demo.xyz?p1=a` ---> rewrite to `http://slim.app/url/demo.xyz?p1=a` through a Varnish proxy
2. Call to `http://slim.app/url/demo.xyz?p1=a` directly

Both calls need to work.

Inside a middleware I set `/url/demo.xyz` as base path so the URLs generated are `http://demo.xyz?p1=a`.

The problems with this are:

- The base path is not recognized by `routes.php` as something to pass params, so `url/abc` is not matched.
- I still need to have the value of the `url` param to fetch some things inside the Slim app.
- My routes need to match this structure to work with both request flows.

```php
 $app->group('/url/{url}', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
    $group->get('[/[/city/{city}]]', IndexAction::class)->setName('home');
    //...
});
```

Any idea to get this to work?

This is connected to the question [placed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59434991/modify-routes-and-url-when-using-varnish).

Answer (score 0):

In the middleware, you can use `Request::getUri()` method to get entire uri. Then, if matches with first url format "http:demo.xyz?p1=a" do:

```
return $response
  ->withHeader('Location', 'https://www.example.com')
  ->withStatus(302);
```

if matches to "http://slim.app/url/demo.xyz?p1=a" do needed stuff to proceed.